# Filtering several date columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with 3 columns. (https://pastebin.com/DFqUuuDp)

The first two columns ("Time1","Time2") contain datetime data and have both the posixct format: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

So what i need ultimately is a subselect of rows, where for a particular time in Time1, only the rows are selected where Time2

- is one day before Time1 (here one day is not always 24 hours; one day means the calendar day before. basically "yesterday")
- **and** Time2 is < 12:00 Am.

A correct example:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
|        Time1        |        Time2         |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2016-11-01 00:00:00 | 2016-10-31 00:00:00  |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

A wrong example:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
|        Time1        |        Time2         |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2016-11-01 00:00:00 | 2016-10-31 12:00:00  |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

In the uploaded file, I added manually the third column ("Value") as a guidance for rows which i want to have filtered at the end. The rows with a "True" are interesting me.

I solved it with two for loops, but it is very slow going through large tables.

Comment: First off, the code from pastebin is giving an error of "Error: unexpected '<' in "  -3000L".  What did you do in the for loop?  This doesn't seem like a problem that needs to be solved with loops.  Have you tried using dplyr and just putting in the conditions in a filter?  i.e.  df %>% filter(time2-time1 <= 1 day & time2  < 12am)?

Comment: sorry, i reuploaded the file. It was a data.table before. Now i i have uploaded a data.frame. ---- I don't know how to formulate (time2-time1 <= 1 day & time2 < 12am). How would you code the 'time2-time1 <= 1 day' part?

Comment: @UDE_Student Your data is very big. Why dont you just share `dput(head(df,20))`? It will be easier for everyone.

Comment: yes you are right, i updated my initial post with the shorter version: https://pastebin.com/DFqUuuDp

Comment: I have added a possible solution in base-R using `lubridate`. Have a look,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been tagged `data.table`. In addition, the sample datasets provided by the OP are of class `data.table`. Therefore, I feel obliged to post a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
DT[as.IDate(Time1) - 1L == as.IDate(Time2) & hour(Time2) < 12]
```

> ```
>                  Time1      Time2 Value
> 1: 2016-11-01 00:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
> 2: 2016-11-01 00:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
> 3: 2016-11-01 01:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
> 4: 2016-11-01 01:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
> ```

```
# check if result is correct
identical(DT[as.IDate(Time1) - 1L == as.IDate(Time2) & hour(Time2) < 12L],
          DT[Value == "TRUE"])
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

`as.IDate()` is a Date class with integer storage for fast sorting and grouping. So, we can use integer arithmetic to compute the previous day. `hour()` is also provided by the `data.table` package and returns the hours of the day as integer value.

#### Reproducible data

Data copied from the [pastebin link provided by the OP](https://pastebin.com/DFqUuuDp) on 2018-05-29 at 22:00 UTC but with the `.internal.selfref` pointer removed:

```
DT <- structure(
  list(
    Time1 = structure(c(1477958400, 1477958400, 1477958400,
                        1477958400, 1477958400, 1477958400, 1477958400, 1477960200, 1477960200,
                        1477960200, 1477960200, 1477960200, 1477960200, 1477960200, 1477962000,
                        1477962000, 1477962000, 1477962000, 1477962000, 1477962000, 1477962000,
                        1477963800, 1477963800, 1477963800, 1477963800, 1477963800, 1477963800,
                        1477963800), 
                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
    Time2 = structure(c(1477699200, 1477742400, 1477785600, 1477828800,
                        1477872000, 1477915200, 1477958400, 1477699200, 1477742400,
                        1477785600, 1477828800, 1477872000, 1477915200, 1477958400,
                        1477699200, 1477742400, 1477785600, 1477828800, 1477872000,
                        1477915200, 1477958400, 1477699200, 1477742400, 1477785600,
                        1477828800, 1477872000, 1477915200, 1477958400), 
                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Value = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
              "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
              "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
              "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
              "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE")), 
  .Names = c("Time1", "Time2", "Value"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -28L), 
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Good use of `as.IDate`! Actually, data provided by `OP` was in `data.frame` when I took it. And I wanted to provide a base-R solution so that `original` row-names in result to give OP an idea which rows were selected.

Comment: great solution, i will give the accepted answer to this question because it does not use the lubridate package

Comment: Thank you. I just want to point out that I find `lubridate` to be a very handy package in many circumstances. However, it is not necessary to use the `days()` function or `lubridate`'s date arithmetic here because we just need to subtract `1` to get the previous day. Both `Date` and `IDate` count days. The difference is that `IDate` uses integer as storage mode.

Comment: question regarding DT[as.IDate(Time1) - 1L == as.IDate(Time2) & hour(Time2) < 12]: I try to adjust this in that way, where i am not interested in Time1 being one calendar day before Time2; but Time1 is one OR more calendar days being before Time2. If i use >=, it is technically correct but it gives me more than one result, where i am interested in only "the latest possible single" Time2. Any ideas?

Comment: ok i solved it with: filtered_dt <- filtered_dt[Time1 > Time2, lapply(.SD, last), by = Time1]

Comment: Glad, you figured it out yourself. Otherwise, I would have suggested to post a new question as this is a completely different problem than just "take the previous date".

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works. The solution uses data shared by `OP`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter((as.Date(Time2)+days(1)) == as.Date(Time1) & format(Time2, "%H") < 12)


#                   Time1      Time2 Value
# 1   2016-11-01 00:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 2   2016-11-01 00:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 3   2016-11-01 01:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 4   2016-11-01 01:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 5   2016-11-01 02:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 6   2016-11-01 02:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 7   2016-11-01 03:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 8   2016-11-01 03:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 9   2016-11-01 04:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 10  2016-11-01 04:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# so on
```

Comment: Two minor comments. 1) You don't need to use `$` in `dplyr` chain. Perhaps, you should try your solution on data shared by `OP` and check if it returns valid output.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `subset` and `lubridate` package can be using an approach as:

1. Add 1 day to `Time2` and then check `Time1` & `Time2` belongs to same day.
2. Format `Time2` in `HHMMSS` format and then check it is less than `120000` (noon)

The code:

```
library(lubridate)

subset(df, format(Time1,"%Y%m%d") == format(Time2+days(1),"%Y%m%d") &
        as.integer(format(Time2, "%H%M%S")) < 120000 )

#                    Time1      Time2 Value
# 19   2016-11-01 00:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 39   2016-11-01 00:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 59   2016-11-01 01:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 79   2016-11-01 01:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 99   2016-11-01 02:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 119  2016-11-01 02:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 139  2016-11-01 03:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 159  2016-11-01 03:30:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 179  2016-11-01 04:00:00 2016-10-31  TRUE
# 
# so on
```

**Note:** `Time2` for all rows as part of subset contains `00:00:00`. Hence its not appearing in above print.

Data:

```
head(df, 20)
# Time1               Time2 Value
# 1  2016-11-01 2016-10-22 00:00:00 FALSE
# 2  2016-11-01 2016-10-22 12:00:00 FALSE
# 3  2016-11-01 2016-10-23 00:00:00 FALSE
# 4  2016-11-01 2016-10-23 12:00:00 FALSE
# 5  2016-11-01 2016-10-24 00:00:00 FALSE
# 6  2016-11-01 2016-10-24 12:00:00 FALSE
# 7  2016-11-01 2016-10-25 00:00:00 FALSE
# 8  2016-11-01 2016-10-25 12:00:00 FALSE
# 9  2016-11-01 2016-10-26 00:00:00 FALSE
# 10 2016-11-01 2016-10-26 12:00:00 FALSE
# 11 2016-11-01 2016-10-27 00:00:00 FALSE
# 12 2016-11-01 2016-10-27 12:00:00 FALSE
# 13 2016-11-01 2016-10-28 00:00:00 FALSE
# 14 2016-11-01 2016-10-28 12:00:00 FALSE
# 15 2016-11-01 2016-10-29 00:00:00 FALSE
# 16 2016-11-01 2016-10-29 12:00:00 FALSE
# 17 2016-11-01 2016-10-30 00:00:00 FALSE
# 18 2016-11-01 2016-10-30 12:00:00 FALSE
# 19 2016-11-01 2016-10-31 00:00:00  TRUE
# 20 2016-11-01 2016-10-31 12:00:00 FALSE
```